# How to Get a file from my parent directory?

Tags: php, html, file

Consider my folder tree as something like this:
`This PC->Local Disk: E->Onuranon`
Now in this `Onuranon` folder, I have a folder named `Bangla` and a text file named `indexed.txt`. What I want is to read the file `indexed.txt` from my file named `bnfirpap.php` whose location is:
`Onuranon->bangla->questions->board-questions->first-paper->bnfirpap.php`
There are also other folders and files here, but I do not need to include them.
Here is the code that I have used:
`file_get_contents("../indexed.txt");`

Now, the file is not read, but it is supposed to. Using `..` in the file name means I have reached the root directory which is `Onuranon` and since `indexed.txt` is in that folder, it is replaced by `Onuranon/indexed.txt` and must be read. But what is the problem?

Comment: you are passing a relative path that should be resolved relative to the current working directory. If you want to know which one it is, `echo getcwd()`. Anyway it should be where your php script is located. But since the path holding "assets" seems detached by the so called document root, just use an absolute path. One last note: `..` doesn't mean you reached the root but it's go up on parent dir by 1 level. On the other hand, starting with `/` means restart from root.

Comment: @DiegoD But what is my root? You said `/` means restart from root, so I am using `/indexed.txt`  then it shall run the file `indexed.txt` from `Onuranon` folder, but it cannot find it. Moreover, I tried using `getcwd()` and came to know about the current working directory and used `../indexed.txt` that worked. Can you tell me more?

Comment: The root in a linux system is the main root.. and would be pretty clear. In a windows env I'm pretty lost because I should try.. I suspect there's still a main root and following the volumes. Since you reported the paths in your question using arrows, I have no idea how they are actually encoded. Anyway the latest comment you made confused me. You are saying that `../indexed.txt` worked and at the same time in the question you said `"../indexed.txt"` didn't work. All I can say is just focus on how paths and the filesystem works. It will answer more question than anything you can ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within any PHP file, you can use `__DIR__` to get the filename of the directory containing that file.  You can then use the `dirname()` function as many times as you need to go 'up' a directory.

From within `Onuranon/bangla/questions/board-questions/first-paper/bnfirpap.php` you could get a reference to the `bangla` folder using this:

```php
$banglaFolder = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

You could then retrieve the contents of your `indexed.txt` file within this folder:

```php
$contents = file_get_contents($banglaFolder . '/indexed.txt');
```

Comment: By using 'up' a directory, you mean I can go backwards in the tree. Thank you for such an info sir. I did not know it before.